# Need help with pspice simulation

Tags: simulation, flipflop, pspice

I made a project of monostable flip flop using 555 timer in pspice. Now I need help with simulation. Problem is that I'm just statring my adventure with pspice and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I guess there is something wrong with Trigger configuration (Vtr - rectangular signal) and I don't know how to configure Setup Analysis properly. I'm trying to achieve output waveform and voltage across the capacitor C.

[image: 555_mono_sh] 
direct link to [.sh file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7ylcjfbubnh2cs/555_mono.sch?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of PSpice are you using. But after adding TR and TF a small value, it works. Usually a 1 picosecond rise/fall time is extremely small with regard to the simulation time, so it closely approximates the ideal step function. Set them to 0 may cause convergence problems in some transient analysis simulations.

Comment: Like I wrote, I new in pspice and I don't know how to configure it :). Can you help me with that? I know that I should setup values it and change Setup Analysis.

Comment: Set the TR and TR parameters of the VPULSE source (Vtr) to a small value such as 1ps, that should be OK.

Comment: If you want to see voltage acroos C the arrow must be placed ABOVE the capacitor (otherwise, you measure always 0 volts).